# evaluating a function along an axis in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a `numpy` function `f` that takes arrays as arguments and a 3D array `x[a,b,c]`.

I would like to evaluate the function `f` along a specific column.  A long-winded way could be with comprehensions:

```python
y = [ [ f(x[a][b])  for a in range(len(x)) ] for b in range(len(x[0]))]
y = np.array(y)
```

Is there a numpy way of doing this with broadcasting?

Answer (score 1):

`np.apply_along_axis(f, 2, x).T`

Comment: Also see the docs in: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler comprehension:

```
numpy.array([[f(row) for row in layer] for layer in x]).T
```

or more concisely,

```
numpy.array([map(f,layer) for layer in x]).T
```

Note that I reproduced the transpose from your sample code.  You can avoid the nested comprehension with cryptic reshaping:

```
numpy.reshape(map(f,x.reshape(numpy.prod(x.shape[:2]), x.shape[2])),x.shape[:2]).T
```